Strange behavior in nvim for lsp virtual_text
I have a strange behavior in nvim with lsp virtual_text. When I enter command mode and exit, the symbol for virtual_text changes to the default symbol.
So how do I stop this strange behavior?


Config for lsp:
    ---@diagnosticjdisable: undefined-global
    return {
      {
        "VonHeikemen/lsp-zero.nvim",
        branch = "v3.x",
        lazy = true,
        config = false,
        init = function()
          -- Disable automatic setup, we are doing it manually
          vim.g.lsp_zero_extend_cmp = 0
          vim.g.lsp_zero_extend_lspconfig = 0
        end,
      },
    
      -- Autocompletion
      {
        "hrsh7th/nvim-cmp",
        event = "InsertEnter",
        dependencies = {
          {
            "L3MON4D3/LuaSnip",
            "rafamadriz/friendly-snippets",
          },
        },
        config = function()
          -- Herk is where you configure the autocompletion settings.
          local lsp_zero = require("lsp-zero")
          lsp_zero.extend_cmp()
    
          -- And you can configure cmp even more, if you want to.
          local cmp = require("cmp")
          local cmp_action = lsp_zero.cmp_action()
    
          -- for vscode snippets
          require('luasnip.loaders.from_vscode').lazy_load()
          cmp.setup({
            formatting = lsp_zero.cmp_format({ details = true }),
            mapping = cmp.mapping.preset.insert({
              ["<C-b>"] = cmp.mapping.scroll_docs(-4),
              ["<C-f>"] = cmp.mapping.scroll_docs(4),
              ["<C-Space>"] = cmp.mapping.complete(),
              ["<C-e>"] = cmp.mapping.abort(),
              ["<CR>"] = cmp.mapping.confirm({
                behavior = cmp.ConfirmBehavior.Replace,
                select = true,
              }),
            }),
            snippet = {
              expand = function(args)
                require("luasnip").lsp_expand(args.body)
              end,
            },
            sources = cmp.config.sources({
              { name = "copilot" },
              { name = "nvim_lsp" },
              { name = "luasnip" },
            }, {
              { name = "buffer" },
            }),
          })
        end,
      },
    
      -- LSP
      {
        "neovim/nvim-lspconfig",
        cmd = "LspInfo",
        event = { "BufReadPre", "BufNewFile" },
        dependencies = {
          { "hrsh7th/cmp-nvim-lsp" },
        },
        config = function()
          -- This is where all the LSP shenanigans will live
          local lsp_zero = require("lsp-zero")
          lsp_zero.extend_lspconfig()
    
          lsp_zero.on_attach(function(client, bufnr)
            -- see :help lsp-zero-keybindings
            -- to learn the available actions
            lsp_zero.default_keymaps({ buffer = bufnr })
          end)
    
          lsp_zero.on_attach(function(client, bufnr)
            lsp_zero.default_keymaps({ buffer = bufnr })
          end)
    
          require("mason").setup({})
          require("mason-lspconfig").setup({
            -- Replace the language servers listed here
            -- with the ones you want to install
            ensure_installed = {
              "clangd",
              "rust_analyzer",
              "pyright",
              "tsserver",
              "html",
              "lua_ls",
              "ast_grep",
              "cssls",
              "gopls",
            },
            handlers = {
              lsp_zero.default_setup,
            },
            vim.diagnostic.config({
              virtual_text = {
                prefix = "--", -- Could be '■', '▎', 'x'
              },
            }),
          })
    
          -- (Optional) Configure lua language server for neovim
          local lua_opts = lsp_zero.nvim_lua_ls()
          require("lspconfig").lua_ls.setup(lua_opts)
    
          lsp_zero.on_attach(function(client, bufnr)
            lsp_zero.default_keymaps({ buffer = bufnr })
          end)
    
          lsp_zero.set_sign_icons({
            error = "",
            warn = "",
            hint = "",
            info = "",
          })
        end,
      },
    }

I am using:

LSB Version: n/a
Distributor ID: Fedora
Description: Fedora Linux 39 (Workstation Edition)
Release: 39
Codename: n/a


So how to stop this and fix the problem?
